# Form validation gives me the right error message but lets the form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

My form validation does not work properly. I would put no value in to it and it will give me the message"please enter valid email" but then it will still add it to my list.

Even when I try to enter a value that is not an email it will give me the right message and it will stop me just once from putting it in my list, but when i push the button again with the same incorrect value it will still add it to my list.

As you can see here:

[image]

This is the list:
[image]

And this my code with form and validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cohorts</title>

 <body>

 <form id="register-form" class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="addCohort()">

<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Name:</label>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" ng-model="formCohort.name">

<input class = "btn-btn-primary" id="submit-button"  type="submit" value="Sigin up">
```

```
<script>
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    agree: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    agree: "Please accept our policy"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
                 });
             }
          };

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
           $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>

  </form>
  </body>
              </html>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ to prevent the default submission action.